# SharePoint 2013 did not return expected result when searching by a property

Tags: search, search-results

I have a document library which has a TitleFrench property, I searched it from search box by (TitleFrench="décision sur l’ACP"). It's supposed to return 44 items, however, it return 43 items. I checked the missing one, it also has the same value. I don't know why it wasn't return. and I also would like to know how to troubleshoot this kind of issue. Thanks

Comment: Is it because the search string includes French character?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your search result web part is configured to trim duplicates.

1. Click the gear icon to Edit the page.
2. Click the down arrow on your Search Results web part and select Edit Web part
3. Click the Change Query button
4. Click the Settings tab and select `Don't trim duplicates`
5. Click OK twice, and save your page

Comment: no. I already unselect "Don't trim duplicates". and if I just targeted this specific item, for example, plus another criteria of this item ID, I didn't get any result. it seems after crawling, this  item's TitleFrench has different value other than 'décision sur l’ACP'